# Whether will dd command jump the bad block of emmc?

Tags: linux, memory, storage, flash-memory

On emmc flash, when we use dd command, will it jump the bad blocks?
I found this link: http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/how-to-fix-repair-bad-blocks-in-linux/
And please notice its "Step 5":

> This step will destroy the data on that block by writing zeroes on it.
>   The bad block will be recovered but the data of the file will be lost.
>   If you are sure, you can proceed with the following step:

```
root]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda3 bs=4096 count=1 seek=2269012
root]# sync
```

Why dd can recover bad block? So these blocks are not really bad/corrupted?
And why sync command is executed after dd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eMMC is more like SSD than raw flash chip.

There is eMMC controller inside eMMC storage. The controller is in charge of mapping spare blocks to bad blocks.

The address before the mapping is called logical address, and the address after the mapping is called physical address.

The physical address is only visible to the controller, OS only see the logical address.

When OS write a logical block, the controller will check the write result, if failed, it will allocate a spare physical block at the broken logical address, then retry write.

By erasing all blocks, forces the controller to check all blocks, if any fails, it will allocate a spare block for the bad block (aka recovery).